# How to reload the page when div becomes empty

Tags: jquery

I have a 'div' with class 'popupDiv' which holds html of popup window. When i close the popup my 'popupDiv' div becomes empty. I want to reload the page when this div becomes empty. Can you suggest if we have any method in jquery which works on element empty.

Comment: why not just bind it to your close event - if you really need to do it only when the div becomes empty then you would need to use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Please share your code what have you tried so far so that we can help you.

Comment: You could use- location.reload(true);  onclose of popup window.